# Testing if my assertion using Ruby and Appium is correct

Tags: android, ruby, appium, appium-android

I wonder if someone can help?
I have created snippets using Ruby for my appium test.
The test passes if the correct page has loaded but I want to know that my fail assertion works as well.

If the below element (mobile_number_text) is on the page I get the 'Correct page is showing' message.
However, what do I have to do to have 'incorrect page is showing' message appear?
I have tried changing the elements' name to 'mobile_text' to trigger the incorrect message but instead my test fails as it cannot find the element.

```
    if find_element(id: "mobile_number_text").displayed?
      puts("Correct page is showing")
    else
      puts("incorrect page is showing")
end
end
```

Many thanks for your time
Zaif

Answer (score 0):

In Java we would have to wrap `find_element(id: "mobile_number_text").displayed?` in a try/catch block so that it does not throw an exception when it cannot find the element. The equivalent in Ruby should work.